# Avoiding Python tricks to find anagrams

Tags: python, python-3.x

**What are anagrams?**

An anagram of a string is another string that contains the same characters, only the order of characters can be different. For example, “abcd” and “dabc” are an anagram of each other

```
def anagram_check(string1,string2):
    list1 = [char1.lower() for char1 in string1 if char1 != " "]
    list2 = [char2.lower() for char2 in string2 if char2 != " "]
    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False
    else:
        list1.sort()
        list2.sort()
        return list1 == list2

print(anagram_check('clint eastwood','old west action'))
```

**Question**

I have started to learn data structures and algorithms, and my question is: Am I using too many Python tricks to solve this problem or do I need to think of a more basic approach to solve this?

Comment: You can look at my `Counter` based solution which is pythonic and one liner. https://www.github.com/strikersps/Competitive-Programming/tree/master/Other-Programs%2FAnagram-Detection%2Fanagram_detection_another_solution.py

Comment: @strikersps doesn't really work for OP's case https://tio.run/##XY4xCsMwDEV3nUJ4siFL062QqScxttIaHMvICqGnd0xLlv7p8XnDqx99c7n3DqvwhoFzpqCJS8O0VRbFJ@9FSQAirehtU0nldZvwB7N7AI4J6S7lki/L4bL8fbMDqAPUemtCHoDkmx7M0UxoOEc8qCn6b4VxrvcT

Comment: *"am I using too much of python tricks"* - What does that even mean? Too much for what?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Agreed; it needs to be `Counter(string1.replace(" ", "").lower()) == Counter(string2.replace(" ", "").lower())` (although that's begging to be made DRY).

Comment: @hjpotter92 Sorry! my bad I didn't take care of spaces in between the strings. Updated the code-base. Thanks!

Comment: Guys, I forgot the email address I used for this account from which I have posted this question. How do recover this account? LOL the question went HOT

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your specific question, I only see a few "tricks" being used in your code:

1. Converting to lower case.
2. Eliminating spaces.
3. Comparing the lengths as a shortcut
4. Sorting the lists to quickly compare them.

None of these are particularly "Python-centric". The only caveat would be that Python strings are \$O(1)\$ to compute the length, while for example C strings are \$O(n)\$ to compute the length.

(Note: while Python's standard `sort()` is faster than C's standard `qsort()`, this is a library thing and not your responsibility.)

One "obvious" thing would be to use `collections.Counter` to generate an equivalence class that would determine whether two strings were anagrams. That definitely *would* be Python-centric, since most other languages don't have a direct equivalent. (Although it's trivial to write in a language that already has dict/hash/assoc-array support.)

That said, let's look at your code from a Python standpoint.

### Does it pep8?

I see a couple of problems with your function from a [PEP-8](https://pep8.org) standpoint.

1. Your function has no [docstring.](https://pep8.org/#documentation-strings)
2. Use spaces after commas.

### Is it quick-like?

You have done a fair job of optimizing the code without becoming "too Pythonic." I would suggest some of the following, however:

1. Only call `.lower()` once. You call `char1.lower() for char1 in string1` but you could instead use `char1 for char1 in string1.lower()` which would call `.lower()` once per string, rather than once per character. This will become significant when someone passes you a 60,000 character string. ;-)
2. Trust the snake! Instead of checking the length, trust Python to do that! You can simplify your code even further with that.

### Fix that name!

Unless you have some kind of requirement that you must use the name, change that name! The name `anagram_check` sounds like a procedure (do something) not like a function (return something). But you're returning a boolean value. So make it a boolean-sounding name:

```
is_anagram_of
are_anagrams
has_anagram
compare_equal_when_sorted_with_spaces_removed
```

Comment: Seems counterproductive that your "Is it quick-like?" part suggests to remove the O(1) length check that can likely avoid unnessecary O(n log n) sorting.

Answer (score 10):

Taking advantage of the work previously submitted by @hjpotter92 and adding an extra twist:

```
def anagram_check(*args ):
    return len( { tuple(sorted(x.lower().replace(' ', ''))) for x in args } ) == 1
```

This, potentially, gains an additional pythonicity score by avoiding repetition of the `sorted(x.lower().replace( ...)` construct. Instead, the construct is applied to both arguments in the set comprehension, and the test to see if the resulting set has a single element provides the answer. This implementation also generalizes the API to cover more that two strings if wanted, returning `True` if all strings given are anagrams of each other (thanks to Heap Overflow for pointing this out).

If you really want a function which is limited to two strings, you might prefer:

```
def anagram_check(string1, string2):
    return len({tuple(sorted(x.lower().replace(' ', ''))) for x in [string1,string2]}) == 1
```

The code can be made less terse and more legible by defining a function to act on each string:

```
def make_unique(x): 
     return tuple( sorted( x.lower().replace(' ', '') ) )

def anagram_check(*args): 
     return len( { make_unique(x) for x in args } ) == 1
```

Comment: It's not a b̶u̶g̶  weakness, it's a feature! With `*args`, you check whether any (positive) number of strings are all anagrams of each other.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily terse.  My eyes have to fly to the middle of the one-liner to get a grasp of what's happening, then work my way out and trust I don't lose track of parenthesis.  I think OP would be better served by taking the spirit of this function and breaking out parts of it, such as `cleaned_string = string.lower().replace(' ','')` and so on.

Comment: `: 'Two or more strings'` and `-> 'True if all strings are anagrams'` - you used type annotations as comments. It doesn't fail at runtime but static code analysers will complain about it and it confuses readers of the code. Please consider editing your answer.

Comment: using type annotations as comments is not their intended purpose at all. and the code leans too much towards brevity than readability.

Comment: I've taken the misused type annotations out .. thanks for the correction.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your suggestions. Converting the list to a set will omit duplicated characters, which we don't want, and I don't know where `ignored=..` can be used.

Comment: @user1717828 : Fair point. I've added an expanded version with a `make_unique` function defined in advance.

Comment: @MJuckes Ah, good point.

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to Code Review.

Since you're looking for Python tricks here, there are great many things which can both make it Pythonic, maintainable, shorter, etc. Depending on your understanding, as well the target audience for the code in near future, you may choose individual methods. A few pointers to get you started:

1. You can use a `filter` to remove all whitespace characters:

   ```
   filter(lambda char: char != ' ', string.lower())
   ```
2. You can use `replace` to replace all whitespaces:

   ```
   string.lower().replace(' ', '')
   ```
3. You can use `collections.Counter` to verify that count of each character in both strings is equal, although list equality works as well.
4. You can validate (or simply return) equality of a `sorted` call on the filtered strings.

---

```
def anagram_check(string1, string2):
    return sorted(string1.lower().replace(' ', '')) == sorted(string2.lower().replace(' ', ''))
```

The one-liner above is perfectly Pythonic, imo.

Comment: Isn't this pretty WET? `reduce` is superseded by what you replaced it from, also it is generally tainted in most Python circles. I would not recommend it in Python 3.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I didn't get you. What does "reduce is superseded ...... circles" mean?

Comment: Ah sorry that's meant to be `filter` not `reduce`. If that's not cleared it up enough; the new Pythonic form of `filter` is generator expressions and list comprehensions (depending on Python version). Additionally [`filter` is depreciated](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#215-deprecated-language-features) in the Google style guide.

Comment: @Peilonrayz oh ok! I know that filter/map now give a generator and not a list. Hence I stated them as "a few pointers" to let the OP do some research of their own.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Hmm, why do you say "you're looking for python tricks"? They're asking "am I using *too much* of python tricks". (And the title has in the meantime been clarified, changed to "*Avoiding* python tricks".)

Comment: @Peilonrayz Where does that Google style guide say `filter` is deprecated? I only see it say that `filter` *with lambda* is. And it says that about `map` as well and explicitly lists `map(math.sqrt, ...` as a "Yes"/"Ok" example.

Comment: Something implicit in your answer and perhaps should be made explicit is that `lower` works on entire strings, not just individual characters.

Comment: @HeapOverflow the OP updated their question within few seconds after i had posted this answer. earlier question was just the opposite :/

Comment: Looking at the history, I see that the "am I using too much of python tricks" was there since the beginning, an hour before your answer. Only the title changed in the meantime, and like I said I think it's a clarification (I'd say "Using" doesn't imply that they *want* to use tricks if the question already asks about "using too much").

Answer (score 3):

I'll focus on performance. Let's first benchmark removing spaces and lower-casing:

```
string1 = 'clint eastwood'; string2 = 'old west action'

6.45 μs  list1 = [char1.lower() for char1 in string1 if char1 != " "]; list2 = [char2.lower() for char2 in string2 if char2 != " "]
0.42 μs  string1.replace(' ', ''); string2.replace(' ', '')
0.25 μs  string1.lower(); string2.lower()
0.63 μs  string1.replace(' ', '').lower(); string2.replace(' ', '').lower()
0.71 μs  string1.lower().replace(' ', ''); string2.lower().replace(' ', '')
```

Your preprocessing is *a lot* slower than using string methods. And unsurprisingly, it's faster to remove spaces *before* lower-casing. Both @M_Juckes and @hjpotter92 did it the other way around.

Now let's check length, sorting and counting of the preprocessed strings:

```
string1 = 'clinteastwood'; string2 = 'oldwestaction'

0.16 μs  len(string1); len(string2)
1.65 μs  sorted(string1); sorted(string2)
6.59 μs  Counter(string1); Counter(string2)
```

Getting the length is far cheaper than sorting and counting, which are also a lot slower than the space-removal and lower-casing and thus make up most of the time. So for performance it's a good idea to do your length check and not sort/count at all if the lengths already differ. Also, counting is far more expensive than sorting. Probably not for a lot longer strings, but I find it unrealistic to check whether two very long strings are anagrams.

Let's turn what we learned into an optimized solution:

```
def anagram_check(string1, string2):
    s = string1.replace(' ', '')
    t = string2.replace(' ', '')
    if len(s) != len(t):
        return False
    return sorted(s.lower()) == sorted(t.lower())
```

First I *only* remove the spaces, so that the length check can avoid unnecessary lowering as well. Then lower-case and use sorting. I kept the longer parameter names for clarity but internally switched to more convenient short variable names.

Benchmarks on full solutions, first with your original string pair:

```
('clint eastwood', 'old west action')

7.97 μs  original
2.69 μs  heap_overflow
3.71 μs  M_Juckes
2.45 μs  hjpotter92
```

Mine is a bit slower than hjpotter92's, as the length check does take a little time. Next let's modify the second string a bit so they're not anagrams:

```
('clint eastwood', 'new west action')

7.74 μs  original
2.62 μs  heap_overflow
3.63 μs  M_Juckes
2.50 μs  hjpotter92
```

Pretty much the same. Now let's make the second string a bit *longer*:

```
('clint eastwood', 'older west action')

6.94 μs  original
0.77 μs  heap_overflow
4.00 μs  M_Juckes
2.64 μs  hjpotter92
```

Now the length check pays off. In my solution more than in yours, as I avoid not only the sorting but also the lower-casing. It's by far the fastest now, as expected from the earlier timings of the individual steps.

I don't know what data you're using this on, but if the length check fails let's say 50% of the time, then it's clearly worth doing, and my solution is fastest on average. I'd also say it's better style than those long one-liners.

Full benchmark code:

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import partial
from timeit import repeat

tests = [
    ('clint eastwood','old west action'),
    ('clint eastwood','new west action'),
    ('clint eastwood','older west action'),
    ]

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

normers = [
    'list1 = [char1.lower() for char1 in string1 if char1 != " "]; list2 = [char2.lower() for char2 in string2 if char2 != " "]',
    "string1.replace(' ', ''); string2.replace(' ', '')",
    "string1.lower(); string2.lower()",
    "string1.replace(' ', '').lower(); string2.replace(' ', '').lower()",
    "string1.lower().replace(' ', ''); string2.lower().replace(' ', '')",
    ]

for test in tests[:1]:
    setup = f'string1 = {test[0]!r}; string2 = {test[1]!r}'
    print(setup)
    tss = [[] for _ in normers]
    for _ in range(3):
        for normer, ts in zip(normers, tss):
            t = min(repeat(normer, setup, number=10**5)) * 10
            ts.append(t)
    for normer, ts in zip(normers, tss):
        print('%.2f μs ' % min(ts), normer)
    print()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

normers = [
    "len(string1); len(string2)",
    "sorted(string1); sorted(string2)",
    "Counter(string1); Counter(string2)",
    ]

for test in tests[:1]:
    string1 = test[0].replace(' ', '').lower()
    string2 = test[1].replace(' ', '').lower()
    setup = f'string1 = {string1!r}; string2 = {string2!r}'
    print(setup)
    setup += '; from collections import Counter'
    tss = [[] for _ in normers]
    for _ in range(3):
        for normer, ts in zip(normers, tss):
            t = min(repeat(normer, setup, number=10**5)) * 10
            ts.append(t)
    for normer, ts in zip(normers, tss):
        print('%.2f μs ' % min(ts), normer)
    print()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

def original(string1,string2):
    list1 = [char1.lower() for char1 in string1 if char1 != " "]
    list2 = [char2.lower() for char2 in string2 if char2 != " "]
    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False
    else:
        list1.sort()
        list2.sort()
        return list1 == list2
    
def heap_overflow(string1, string2):
    s = string1.replace(' ', '')
    t = string2.replace(' ', '')
    if len(s) != len(t):
        return False
    return sorted(s.lower()) == sorted(t.lower())

def M_Juckes(*args : 'Two or more strings') -> 'True if all strings are anagrams':
    return len( { tuple(sorted(x.lower().replace(' ', ''))) for x in args } ) == 1

def hjpotter92(string1, string2):
    return sorted(string1.lower().replace(' ', '')) == sorted(string2.lower().replace(' ', ''))

funcs = original, heap_overflow, M_Juckes, hjpotter92

for test in tests:
    print(test)
    print()
    tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
    for _ in range(3):
        for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
            t = min(repeat(partial(func, *test), number=10**5)) * 10
            ts.append(t)
    for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
        print('%.2f μs ' % min(ts), func.__name__)
    print()
```